# Fill entire SQL table column

Tags: sql

I just added a new column in my DB which I need to propagate with a specific text value (Confirmed). Is there a simple way to apply to all my data entries so I don't have to go through all my rows and type the value in?

Thanks

Comment: I need an example of what exactly you want to insert and where. Your question is entirely too vague.

Answer (score 49):

you run the statement:

```
UPDATE whateveryourtableis SET whateveryourcolumnis = 'whatever';
```

Comment: This is correct (+1), but be careful.  Dave is answering your question specifically, but an UPDATE without a WHERE clause is not generally what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Beware, Russ, as this will overwrite any and all data in the column you update all at once. For large tables, this operation will consume lots of resources, too (disk/memory/log/etc.). I once did this to a table on a machine with low disk space...and there was not fun to be had. I'm talking about huge tables, though...100k-1m+ rows

Comment: Here's a double barrel shotgun, both barrels filled with double-aught buck and a hair trigger.  Don't go shootin' yourself in the foot now...

Answer (score 14):

Yould could make the desired value the new column's `DEFAULT` e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD 
   my_new_column VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Confirmed' NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is much much faster than the UPDATE method.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = 'Confirmed'
```